# Sometimes there's no result for a search that normally have results

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, search

There is an issue that I've been working around for the last few days and I can't find how to fix it.
I have a site, in Magento 1.9, working with default magento search (we know it have it's issues), and it normally works fine, when I search for some item it will find it.
[image: Site finds the product]

However, if I keep searching the same word for a while, sometimes it will return no results.
[image: Site can't find the product]

I've found this site edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/magento-no-search-results.html where they address this issue but don't say exactly how to fix it, I'm new to Magento so I don't know how to do any of the two methods they mention.
Is there anyone that can tell me how to do it (and where), or if there's any other way to deal with this issue?
Thanks a lot in advance!!.